# WPF: Dynamically change dependency property value for all user controls of same type

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

I'm rather new to WPF and encountered some difficulties with user controls.

Please consider the following scenario:
I have a WPF application with a user control, say

```
MySpecialButtonControl
```

This "button" has two appearances "oldStyle" and "newStyle" (specified by the Enum "AppearanceStyle") which are controlled by a dependency property with the name

```
MyLayoutProperty
```

The callback function has to carry out the code which changes the layout.
Now here is what I would like to do:
I need to change the appearance of all (!) instances of the user control in this window at once in a code-behind file at run-time.

Binding (e.g.) a property to individual instances of the UC like

```
Binding binding = new Binding("AppearanceStyle");
binding.Source = myOptionsClass;
this.myButton.SetBinding(UserControls.MySpecialButtonControl.MyLayoutProperty, binding);
```

works perfectly well. But how can I directly change the dependency property for ALL UC instances without having to iterate over collections of the UCs, etc.? Is there even a way to achieve this in WPF/C#?

I tried to solve this problem by using styles, but changing the style which is shared by all UCs itself at runtime is not possible since it is already in use (and the UCs which use this style have already been drawn).

Next, I tried to use a dynamic resource in the style like this:

```
  <uc:MySpecialButtonControl x:Key="myFakeButton" ></uc:MySpecialButtonControl >

    <Style x:Key="myButtonStyle" TargetType="uc:MySpecialButtonControl ">
        <Setter Property="MyLayoutProperty" Value="{DynamicResource myFakeButton}"></Setter>
    </Style>
```

This allows me to change the "MyLayoutProperty" for "myFakeButton" at runtime which is half of what I want, but even after googling for some time I still could not find a way to bind the "MyLayoutProperty" of "myFakeButton" to the setter which is what I really need.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

***Update***:
I tried to implement the solution provided by Michael, but unfortunately, I got the following exception:

```
PropertyMetadata is already registered for type 'MySpecialButtonControl'.
```

After some googling (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597491.aspx)) I found that the OverrideMetadata call should be placed in a static constructor of "MySpecialButtonControl" which I did:

```
static MySpecialButtonControl()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
    typeof(MySpecialButtonControl),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MySpecialButtonControl)));
}
```

Now, the application compiles. And now it works perfectly.

Comment: If you bind all your controls to the myOptionsClass object and this object is implemented as a singleton (only one class instance alive) you should be able to update all controls by simply changing the bound property of myOptionsClass. if myOptionsClass implements INotifyPropertyChanged or uses Dependency Properties the changed value should be copied to every instance of your UC automatically (that's what data binding is all about)

Comment: Thanks for the idea - it would work for manually binding the UCs to the Dependency property, but this is not what I want: I do not want to do the data binding by hand for each control. Suppose I dynamically create a new UC somewhere in the code (may be a very complex scenario) and "forget" to bind it to the myOptionClass. => Then its appearance would not be changed by changing the Dependcy property. => No a good code maintenance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I follow, but I'll attempt an answer. Please comment if this is close, and I'll edit until we get there.

All controls in WPF have a property `DefaultStyleKey`. Any derived custom control or user control can use this property to set the key of the default style. At runtime, the framework will try to find a resource of this key. It is common to set the default style key equal to the runtime type of the class.

```
public MySpecialButtonControl()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
        typeof (MySpecialButtonControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof (MySpecialButtonControl)));

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

When a control placed onto a Window, the framework will look in the available resources for a resource with the key that is defined by `DefaultStyleKey`. The resource can be defined in a number of places. Google "WPF resource resolution" for more info. The simplest way to illustrate is to show the default style defined in your App.xaml.

```
<Application.Resources>

    <!-- the default style for MySpecialButtonControls -->
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type uc:MySpecialButtonControl}"
           TargetType="{x:Type uc:MySpecialButtonControl}"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type UserControl}}" >
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
    </Style>

</Application.Resources>
```

Now suppose you have two different styles that you want to switch between at runtime. You might define those styles in your App.xaml.

```
<Application.Resources>

    <!-- the first style -->
    <Style x:Key="Style1"
           TargetType="{x:Type uc:MySpecialButtonControl}"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type UserControl}}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
    </Style>

    <!-- the second style -->
    <Style x:Key="Style2"
           TargetType="{x:Type uc:MySpecialButtonControl}"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type UserControl}}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    </Style>

    <!-- the default style, now based on Style1 -->
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type uc:MySpecialButtonControl}"
           TargetType="{x:Type uc:MySpecialButtonControl}"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource Style1}" />

</Application.Resources>
```

At runtime, you could do something like this to toggle the default style of the controls.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // get the style resources
    var style1 = FindResource("Style1") as Style;
    var style2 = FindResource("Style2") as Style;
    var defaultStyle = FindResource(typeof (MySpecialButtonControl)) as Style;
    if (style1 == null || style2 == null || defaultStyle == null)
        return;

    // create a new style based on the "other" style
    var newDefaultStyle = new Style(
        typeof (MySpecialButtonControl),
        (defaultStyle.BasedOn == style1 ? style2 : style1));

    // set the application-level resource to the new default style
    Application.Current.Resources[typeof (MySpecialButtonControl)] = newDefaultStyle;
}
```

Is this even close?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Michael! I believe this is one way to achieve what I want - I will try it out tomorrow immediately.

Comment: One more question: How would you solve the problem if you could not use style files (imagine a scenario where the changes in the UC layout would be so complex and have many interdependencies that they can not be represented by a simple style in XAML, but would need to be implemented in C#). Is there a way to trigger a change in the value of the dependency property (MyLayoutProperty) for all (!) instances of the UCs without binding "myOptionsClass" manually to each UC?

Comment: I guess I can answer my question myself now. :) I can create two (or more) different styles which just differ in the value for the dependency property. Changing the style will then automatically trigger the dependency proprty callback where I can place any code which has to be carried out when switching a layout.

Comment: Tried your solution but ran into some problems - see update of my original question.

Comment: Problems solved. The control couldn't find the style resource but now it works. Thanks a lot!